# Is it natural to use 'once' with 'used to'?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

Is it natural to use 'once used to' as in the following construction?

I once used to read the Times everyday.

Comment: You can say "At one time I used to read The Times every day" but, even though 'once' could be said to mean 'at one time' you can't replace 'At one time' with 'once in this context because 'at one time' in this case is an idiomatic expression. However you could say "Once upon a time I used to read The Times every day" because that is also an idiomatic expression.

Comment: @BoldBen: l appreciate your generous comment. When l first read the sentence, l knew that using 'once' beside 'used to' sounded weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "once" or "used to" separately but they are generally not used together. As in, "I once read the Times every day" or "I used to read the Times every day."